# {"errorMessage": "Unable to unmarshal input: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)", "errorType": "Runtime.UnmarshalError", "stackTrace": []}

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, lambda

I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/geekculture/deploying-pytorch-model-as-a-serverless-service-339b4b93e517).

Steps:

I downloaded [this github](https://github.com/anandsm7/BERT_as_serverless_service).

from where I installed the project, I executed this:

```
docker build -t logbert-lambda .
docker run -p 8080:8080 logbert-lambda
```

I opened my navigator and I typed: `http://localhost:8080/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations`

It gave me this error: `{"errorMessage": "Unable to unmarshal input: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)", "errorType": "Runtime.UnmarshalError", "stackTrace": []}`

Can't I use my navigator rather than Postman ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial is clear about what HTTP method you have to use:

The endpoint `functions/function/invocations` handles requests of type `POST` and requires some url encoded data in the body:

[image]

---

If you use your browser, you are making a `GET` request and, of course, posting no data.

Comment: I didn't know, thanks for the help ! I successfully did it in Postman :) isn't there a way to do a `POST` request from the navigator ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone doing this with a GET request and you've changed your http definition to GET also while testing specifically in Postman, refer to the picture below I was ale to get it working by adding a `{}` to the body of my GET request.

[image]